# How to initialize Boolean type to be used by local variables?

Tags: delphi, boolean, delphi-xe7

I am trying to change how I use Boolean parameters to have meaningful names, so I don't need to check every method what True/False mean. In this example I use True/False:

```
procedure ProcessData(Param1, Param2: string; CreateOnEmpty: boolean = False);

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProcessData(P1, P2, True);  // when CreateOnEmpty should be True
  ProcessData(P1, P2);        // when CreateOnEmpty should be False
  ProcessData(P1, P2, False); // when CreateOnEmpty should be False
end;
```

But in this case I need to look up ProcessData method to see what True/False parameters mean, do.

So, I started with this example, to assign meaningful names to parameters:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vCreateWhenEmpty: boolean;
  vDontCreateWhenEmpty: boolean;
begin
  // Init control params
  vCreateWhenEmpty := True;
  vDontCreateWhenEmpty := False;

  ProcessData(P1, P2, vCreateWhenEmpty);     // When CreateOnEmpty should be True
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vDontCreateWhenEmpty); // When CreateOnEmpty should be False
end;
```

But, I would like to avoid Initalizing local variables and was thinking of something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);

Type
  TBoolTrue = Boolean = True;    // Init to True and all local vars will be True
  TBoolFalse = Boolean = False;  // Init to False and all local vars will be False

var
  vCreateWhenEmpty: TBoolTrue;      // Variable should default to True
  vDontCreateWhenEmpty: TBoolFalse; // Variable should default to False
begin
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vCreateWhenEmpty);     // When CreateOnEmpty should be True
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vDontCreateWhenEmpty); // When CreateOnEmpty should be False
end;
```

So, I could skip assigning value True/False.

I have 100s of methods that accept Boolean parameters, so 100s of constants or global variables which I can use as parameters sound overkill.

**Is it possible to somehow initialize Boolean type to True/False or avoid initializing local variables with some other trick?**

**EDIT:**

I relaized in example I set Boolean types as local types, I meant to set them as global so they are only set once and not each time in each method.
So, this would be global and not local:

```
Type
      TBoolTrue = Boolean = True;    // Init to True and all local vars will be True
      TBoolFalse = Boolean = False;  // Init to False and all local vars will be False
```

**EDIT 2:**

I hope the question doesn't get closed as there are some good suggestion in the answers. So my options are:

- Global constants (I will end up with 100s of new constants)
- Global enumerated fields (even though I will end up with 100s of them, as with consts, they allow easier expansion of values if I add a third value)
- Local consts (I like this one as its short, 1 line per const and it's local, not global)
- Local variables (2 lines per variable, definition and value init - too much)
- Local enumerated fields (I like this one as it's expandable with third or fourth values...)
- Sir Rufo's example with auto initialized records (though a bit over the top, but is exactly what I was looking for; unfortunately a really over the top implementation; performance would probably be hit, but solution is available - nice)
- Leave it as it is and rely on code-insight for quick understanding of parameters - unfortunately in XE7 is not stable and can't be relied on; maybe in newer versions is better, but from feedback on newer version, I doubt it will ever work as expected.

**DECISION**

Even though Sir Rufo's trick on how to do what I was thinking of was unique, I realized I was trying to achieve something that is not in realm of current Delphi versions. So, I will use a combination of consts and enumerated types and apply only where really necessary, not everywhere and will avoid 100s of global, local variables.

Comment: Bad idea. Explicit code will be easier to maintain.

Comment: You're asking if it's possible to initialize something so you can avoid initializing it. Huh?

Comment: @RobKennedy Yes: initialize global value once and reference this value with local variable.

Comment: Deep confusion. Use `False` or `True` as natured intended. Constants if you want to name them. Look for simplicity.

Comment: Why not making local typed constant like const vCreateWhenEmpty: Boolean = True. It will be located in the data segment, not stack and you still have it accessible only locally without garbaging the global space as in  answer below.

Comment: @ZENsan OK, local const is an option, too, didn't think about that.

Comment: @ZENsan: The suggestion of global scope was under the understanding that they were to be used in more than one place. If not, local constants would work fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to auto-initialize local variables. You'll have to do so in code, or (despite not wanting to) use `const` instead of types, declared at the same scope as the function that will use them.

```
const
  vCreateWhenEmpty = True;
  vDontCreateWnenEmpty = False;

procedure ProcessData(Param1, Param2: string; CreateOnEmpty: boolean = False);
```

Later:

```
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vCreateWhenEmpty); 
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vDontCreateWhenEmpty);
```

I personally would replace the Boolean variables with an enumerated type with a common prefix.

```
type
  TProcessDataCreateOpt = (coCreate, coSkip);

  procedure ProcessData(Param1, Param2: string; CreateOpt: TProcessDataCreateOpt = coSkip);
```

This makes it much more readable, Code Insight and Code Completion can help you with the proper values, and you don't need any local or global variables at all.

Comment: Would like to avoid creating 100s of consts for all the methods that receive Boolean value. Because Create(Dont)WhenEmpty is only applicable name for 1 method (or maybe 2). Would need to create 100s of consts with different names to explain parameters for different methods.

Comment: OP said he wanted to avoid using const in his question

Comment: @JohnEasley: Was editing in other options when you wrote.

Comment: enumerated types are perfect in this case +1

Comment: @JohnEasley: yes, but it is effectively the same as declaring `const` values, which the OP does not want to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau not necessarily true because the parameter declarations could match the enumerated types..

Comment: @JohnEasley: Yes, an enumeration is an *ideal* solution in general, but that still requires declaring the enumeration type separate from the method(s) that use it. That would not be unlike declaring constants instead, but is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The OP is effectively doing more work by trying to create the two types and then create two local variables of those two types that are pre-initialized. That's four lines of code (two type declarations plus two var declarations) as opposed to a single type declaration for the enum. The question itself is an XY problem; a proper design with enums means the problem being addressed doesn't exist.

Comment: If I use enums then I can check `CreateOpt` parameter value with `If CreateOpt = coCreate then...` Which is good, too. OK.

Comment: @KenWhite I realized that and moved types out of local method to global. Makes sense that this would only be set once. So, two lines per method, now. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As others said there is currently no way to initialize local variables, but the real question is why that should be variables at all. It is my understanding from your code that after initializing those variables in code they will never change their value. Also the method does not declare these parameters as variables. In this case, it can also be accomplished by local constants (just to avoid global constants). So instead of declaring local variables and initialize them in code, just declare local constants.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  cCreateWhenEmpty = True;
  cDontCreateWhenEmpty = False;
begin
  ProcessData(P1, P2, cCreateWhenEmpty);     // When CreateOnEmpty should be True
  ProcessData(P1, P2, cDontCreateWhenEmpty); // When CreateOnEmpty should be False
end;
```

On the long run I would also suggest declared enumeration types used as parameters, but in case you are not in the position to change the declaration, the above solution should match the requirements mentioned in your question quite well.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to auto initialize local variables.

But we can create a record that will behave like an auto initialized local variable.

```
type
  TBoolDefaultTrue = record
  private const
    InitializedFlag = '*';
    DefaultValue = True;
  private
    FIsInitialized: string;
    FValue: Boolean;
    procedure EnsureInitialized;
  public
    class operator implicit ( const v: Boolean ): TBoolDefaultTrue;
    class operator implicit ( const v: TBoolDefaultTrue ): Boolean;
  end;

procedure EnsureInitialized;
begin
  if FIsInitialized = ''
  then 
    begin
      FValue := DefaultValue;
      FIsInitialized := InitializedFlag;
    end;
end;

class operator TBoolDefaultTrue.Implicit( const v: Boolean ): TBoolDefaultTrue;
begin
  Result.FValue := v;
  Result.FIsInitialized := InitializedFlag;
end;

class operator TBoolDefaultTrue.Implicit( const v: TBoolDefaultTrue ): Boolean;
begin
  v.EnsureInitialized;
  Result := v.FValue;
end;
```

and you can use it without changing your method signature

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vCreateWhenEmpty: TBoolDefaultTrue;
  vDontCreateWhenEmpty: TBoolDefaultFalse;
begin
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vCreateWhenEmpty);     // When CreateOnEmpty should be True
  ProcessData(P1, P2, vDontCreateWhenEmpty); // When CreateOnEmpty should be False
end;
```

This is only one option you can choose, but to me that is not the one I would prefer for this. I like the enum way as Ken describes in his answer. I would only choose different names.

```
TProcessDataOption = ( pdoDontCreateWhenEmpty, pdoCreateWhenEmpty );
```

But that is only sugar

Comment: That actually works, I like it, but as you said, it seems a bit overkill. I assume this is also not applicable where performance is needed.

Comment: I'd prefer better names for the enums too, but I figured that the OP could name them as they saw fit for their own code. This solution is definitely unique (and rather slick), but I don't see it as being anything I'll use anytime in the near future. :-) Upvoted for the inventive solution, though. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others already suggested, you could use enums instead of booleans, if you can change the implementation of your ProcessData method:

```
type
  TCreateDisposition = (cdDontCreate, cdCreateIfEmpty);

procedure ProcessData(Param1, Param2: string; CreateDisposition: TCreateDisposition);
```

Comment: I mentioned enums in my answer.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry, I missed that.

Comment: You can always "change" the signature also if you do not have access to the original source ˋprocedure Bar( arg: string ); begin FooUnit.Bar( arg = '*' ); end;ˋ ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should leave it how you have it. If you want to see what the name of the parameter is you can simply use code insight to do so.

If you don't already use these then you should start and make your life way easier:

- Ctrl + Shift + Spacebar  Invoke code parameter hints     Delphi 5 and up
- Ctrl + Shift + UpArrow   Navigate to method implementation/declaration
  Delphi 5 and up
- Ctrl + Click  Goes to declaration.

Comment: Lots of times it doesn't work or takes a long time to finish the 'Parsing...' when trying to use code insight.